# Swift Cocoa - Xcode 8: Unable to bind TextField property to @IBOutlets

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I am new to iOS programming and I am building a simple swift application that calculate a loan interest. I did create a separate class to handle the logic and designed successfully my view. I am trying now to bind each textfield to the @IBOutlets I have created but I am unable to do so as you can see through this animation.

[image]

However, when I do try to bind the textField in the View Controller Scene to the @IBOutlets the custom class presented is NSDefaultUserController and after binding it the text fields are not responding when I launch the app. Here below is what I mentioned. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Edit: Better Explanation:
I am trying to connect all the IBOutlets and IBAction to the UI elements loanField, InterestField and TermField. But when I try to drag them to their respective field it does not work as I showed in the first screen.

Comment: @matt To make it clear, I am trying to connect all the IBOutlets and IBAction to the UI elements loanField, InterestField and TermField. But when I try to drag them to their respective field it does not work as I showed in the first screen.

Comment: @matt I just figure out something based on what you said. In creating my project in Xcode if I unselect use storyboard it gives me a file myapplicatiion.xib instead of my application.storyboard. And the connections work with that one. Now why? When do we use storyboard and when we do not? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To bind a property to a TextField in IB. You should bind them first. [Specify a custom class for the storyboard or nib. "TestViewController" in the case.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlaJH.png)

Then you should be able to connect any module (maybe a textField~) in IB to the class's accord property.

Answer (score 0):

> I am new to iOS programming

The first problem is that you don't know the difference between iOS and macOS. You are not doing any iOS programming at all. You have created a MacOS X desktop Cocoa project, not an iOS project. So you're operating in a completely different world.

The second problem is that you are using a storyboard but you don't understand how a storyboard works. With a storyboard, you have a scene with your interface and a view controller. You can only make outlets and actions from objects in that scene to one another. So you would connect a text field in a scene to that scene's view controller — not to the app delegate, which is not part of the scene.